# Generalization of closed range theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

For Hilbert spaces $X$ and $Y$, the closed range theorem is ok if the operator $T:X\rightarrow Y$ has a closed range. But do we in general have
\begin{equation}
Y=\overline{\operatorname{ran}(T)}\oplus \operatorname{ker} (T^*)
\end{equation}
if the range is not closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is true since $\operatorname{ker}(T^*)^{\bot}=\overline{\operatorname{ran}(T)}$...